# Cannot see pictures and cannot hear audio on Galaxy Y; package data not signed properly

Tags: samsung-galaxy-y

I don't know what's wrong with my Galaxy Y. When I take pictures or download pictures, they cannot be viewed. Audios can not be played. I tried downloading Facebook, Viber and Wattpad, but it keeps on saying package data was not signed properly.

Comment: What about the media files that is already present in the phone?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! There are some possibly related [questions on "package not signed correctly"](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=package+not+signed+correctly+is%3Aquestion+answers%3A1) you might wish to check.

Answer (score 1):

Actually galaxy y default player doesn't support much formats.
Check which format it is. Then try downloading the player which supports the format.For eg: if it is 3gp format videos you will need 3gp player.